# Centered site container with growing header to the right using CSS

Tags: css, html

second try as I was unluck to explain the issue yesterday. I am trying to achieve the following layout in html/CSS:

[image]

The grey box is the 1040px wide centered site container. Above is a header with a much wider picture which shall grow to the right side in case of a larger screen resolution. How could I do this with CSS?
I know that I could calculate the left margin of the site container with javscript and dynamically set the left margin of the header, but I want a css solution.

Regards,
Martin

Comment: where is your code?????

Comment: Could you show us your actual code and css?, it's hard to see it without an example.

Comment: There is no code beside two div's because I would like to finish the main problem first and then do the rest to avoid interferences. Heres a link to the bigger picture: http://www.cosketch.com/Saved/pYNIz3gW The blue box is the header, the box below the centered site. The upper one is the optimized screen, below the line how it shall look like if the screen is wider. Makes more sense?

Answer (score 1):

It's me again, I now finally understand what you mean.
The closest I've been able to get to what you want, is trying things out with **percentages**.

```
<div id = "header">
</div>

<div id = "sitecontainer">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header{
height: 200px;
width: 100%px;
background-color: black;
margin-left: 25%;
}
```

Try fiddeling around with those percentages until you hit a sweetspot that works for you.

**To add**; making 2 divs might even be better, something like this: http://puu.sh/3thxc/085a639816.png. But I can't seem to be able to place the second div (headerright) right next to header div.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution which is working but not the sweetest, so if you have a better approach, let me know:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#growing-header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 2400px;
  background-color: #edf034;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #00aaff;
}
```

and the containers:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="growing-header">my header...</div>
    <!-- some more divs, site-content,...</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Cheers,
Martin